# WMI query to find CPU usage for each core

Tags: powershell-2.0, cpu-usage, wmi-query

Is there a WMI/Power-shell query for finding out CPU usage for each different core.

I had used "**select LoadPercentage from Win32_Processor**", but it gives only one value , say 65. But I wish to have Four different values, if My PC have four cores.

**It seems I have got the solution**

I just found "**SELECT Name, percentprocessortime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation**" this query, I think it will solve my issue. Please correct me If I am wrong..
Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation is better one. However still i have doubt on how it will behave in multiple physical processor environment. For more info on that, please check below thread.
[CPU load percentage for individual processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956471/cpu-load-percentage-for-individual-processors)